# Drupal 8 - how to customise search result template

Tags: twig, drupal-theming, drupal-8

I have a custom content type with several fields like Price, Product Summary, Product image etc. Is there any way I can access these fields separately on search result page?

I printed the rendered array on `mytheme/item-list.html.twig` using `kint(item.value)` which shows that I can only access `title`, `url` and `type` separately like `{{ item.value['#result'].url }}`, `{{ item.value['#result'].title }}`. But don't see variables like `product_image`, `product_summary` etc. in rendered array.

According to Twig template suggestion the template I need to override is `search-result.html.twig`. So I copied `/core/themes/stable/templates/content/search-result.html.twig` to my theme's folder. However, the `{{ snippet }}` variable does not have information I want to access.

I went through the following steps to customise the result output:

1. Went to `/admin/structure/types/manage/product/display` (`Structure > Content Types > Product > Manage Display)`. Turned on `Search Index` and `Search result highlight input`.

[image]

2. Navigated to `Search result highlight input` tab and added (enabled) two fields Product summary and Product price

[image]

3. Went back to search result but I still cannot see the those variables in rendered array.

Can somebody please tell me the best way to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 1):

@Subrata Sarkar There is one option. Firstly,install two module search_api and search_api_page module from drupal.org

https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api

https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_page
 [image]

Add server and index in search api.
Add the fields which you want to display on page within index and after                      all configuration indexed all your data.
[image]

After this create and configure search page.And choose view mode option and select a view mode ex:  Search result highlighting input or Search index etc. 
[image]

Hope you get your desired result on search page.For more information,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNilEVQu94I

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I will try your suggestion asap and get back to you what I get.